# Porting VC 6.0 Application to VS 2003 VC++ application

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++

I have an application which is written in VC++ using VC 6.0 version. Now i open the project in VS2003. Does my project now have any link or relation with .Net framework as i am not using the .Net framework.

Will the VC 7 compiler bring about a relationship with . Net.

Comment: Your real concern is language incompatibility. :)

Comment: Porting from a 12 year old compiler to a 7 year old one.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Porting to a current compiler is easier done in two smaller steps than in one big step. Fix all bugs that surface after the port to VC7 (compile and runtime), and then port again to VC10. You only refactor in the last step, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no requirement to use .NET with VS 2003 (or VS 2008 or VS 2010).  You can bring your VC 6.0 project over to VS 2003 and it will still be a native project.